# more audio problems in 15.04

Tags: sound, alsa, headphones, volume-control, speakers

recent update has brought a plethora of audio problems.

PC 15.04 x64, 
DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntustudio

- -keyboard volume controls don't work anymore (known issue, IIRC)
- -Panel volume control on the desktop doesn't work (right clicking can access audio mixer, where the Master volume slider works)
- App volume controls work. (chrome, clementine, etc..)
- -I use both headphones and external speakers.  recently, if I shut down with  my headphones connected, at reboot, there is no speaker
  audio (headphone OR external).  IF I unplug my headphones, then
  speaker audio resumes....sometimes.
- Opening Alsamixer and resetting the "Side" control with "M" (Unmute)
  brings back "normal" speaker functioning (speakers on except when
  headphones are plugged in, and vice-versa).

Comment: try this workaround https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure